# Next.js sending huge image payload as json

Tags: reactjs, performance, web, next.js, lighthouse

I was trying to optimize a Next.js application when I was checking the google page speed report there I found that Next.js sends huge payload js to the browser when client requests for that page. Surprisingly when I open that script I found most of the data is actually image data

which looks like something like this:

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAdIAAAKhBAMAAAAWEDL3AAAAJHpUWHRDcmVhdG9yAAAImXNMyU9KVXBMK0ktUnBNS0tNLik...

It is around 6.00+MB which is huge
how do I fix this issue? Thanks for your time

Comment: This is the website I'm trying to improve https://www.my-iclinic.co.uk/

Comment: is it hosted on vercel?

Comment: @Yilmaz Yes it's hosted on vercel